# Is there any size limit for the compress command?

Tags: compression

Is there any particular size limit after which the `compress` command works?

As I know for 0 byte file, the `compress` command does not work.
But today I tried to compress a file of byte size 27 bytes using the `compress` command in UNIX, but it is not compressing. The file remains unchanged.

Comment: If all 27 bytes are unique, can it be compressed? Further, if it can be compressed, how big would the compression metadata be?

Comment: What command did you use?

Comment: compress command

Comment: i just created one file using the folloing
$ cat > test
31314124
ffsfff
fsfsdf
Then i tried to compress this file, but it is not doing.

Comment: I have found that sometimes the commands are now a little smarter about this and may not do the compress.  I would be surprised if you did not get some type of warning or error message indicating this fact.

Comment: Giving compress the `-f` option will force it to write out a compressed file even if the compressed version is larger than the original. A 0-length file compresses to 3 bytes with the version of compress on Ubuntu.

Comment: @mdpc .. Ya..am getting error like "--File unchanged". Its not like error, but it is showing like the `compress` command refuses to compress the file.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what is in the file (the [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28information_theory%29), roughly). Given completely random contents `compress` would actually<sup>1</sup> make the file larger, and most implementations will refuse to do anything (the [`-v`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/compress.html#tag_20_23_04) option will often tell you this).

A file that contains entirely zero bytes will be compressed to a minimum of 8 bytes on the implementation I have to hand. I suppose that is the size limit, below which the magic number at the start of the compressed file and the basic "repeat this N times" instruction are longer than any input.

Given more usefully-distributed contents (like text) it varies pretty dramatically, but the threshold will be somewhere well into the tens of bytes at least. I wouldn't expect a 27-byte text file to compress, and an arbitrary 27-byte binary file even less so.

<sup>1</sup> Of course, technically, it's random, so...

Comment: Yes Michael, while am trying to compress it refuses to do anything. Gives error like (--file unchanged). But didn't get your comments properly.. what is "repeat N times" means?

Comment: Compression algorithms represent data by encoding instructions to reconstruct it that are shorter than the original data (more or less). Have a look at, say, [Wikipedia on data compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_compression). The details aren't important here.

Comment: Importantly, though, **compression algorithms are not magic** - not everything can be made smaller. If it could, you'd just keep applying it to the output repeatedly until all your data was one byte long.

Comment: yup @Michael Homer, that's true: compression algo are not magic. that's why my qs... **if there any size limit known to anyone where after only `compress` will work?** If the file size would be smaller than that size, then it should refuse.

Comment: It is data-dependent.

Comment: text compresses really nicely for instance, however, many data files and executables generally do not.

Answer (score 0):

Call

```
compress -f your_file_to_compress
```

to force `compress` to behave predictably.

It is a very unpleasant feature - `compress` sometimes decides to arbitrarily leave the file unchanged, but unfortunately the side effect is that the file keeps its original name and does not change to `.Z`.

I would tend to say rather *willfully* than *arbitrarily*. If you call the `compress` from a script and then you count with the existence of the file with the extension `.Z`, you may be very unpleasantly surprised.